# using legacy project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I wish to use "C" legacy project in the Eclipse. In the project it require "autoreconf 
-vi" followed by "./configure" before make to start. My problem is I am not able to do "autoreconf -vi" and "./configure" from the eclipse.

Thanks
Arpit

Answer (score 1):

You should try enabling the autotools features from the *Eclipse Linuxtools Plugin*: if you have CDT, the Linuxtools plugin should already be available in your eclipse environment. However, you need to enable features from it:

- use the following menu: Help / Install New Software
- in the search box type "linux", find the plugin and
- check the box (+ OK)
- finally select at least Linux "Tools/Autotools support for CDT" (also call graph, gcov, gprof, ltt could be interesting but not needed for your problem)

Note: if you do not already have the plugin available, detailed instructions with an update URL are available in the [Linux Tools Project/PluginInstallHelp](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp) wiki page.

Once you have this plugin installed, you can:

1. Convert an existing project by: File / New / Convert to a C/C++ Autotools Project / Next / Next / Finish
2. Edit the project properties as needed: Project / Properties / Autotools / Configure Settings, e.g., to specify configure flags in the advanced tab, platform specifiers for cross compilation etc.

Hope it'll help.

Cheers,
Christophe.

= They did not know it was impossible, so they did it! --Mark Twain =

Answer (score 0):

The use of "autoconf" and similar hacks is no longer required. They were needed to port C code to platforms that failed to properly support ISO C89, but did made a reasonable attaempt. We're 21 years later and such systems are quite rare.

So, you should check for the use of [Autoconf macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Preprocessor-Symbol-Index.html#Preprocessor-Symbol-Index) and remove those.

Scrapping `./configure` might be harder, but it's also possible you might not need it at all - it could exist only as a result of `autoconf`.

Comment: I can not scrap configure or "autoreconf -vi".